# Django 1.7 Changed name of template now TemplateDoesNotExist Error

Tags: python, html, django, templates, django-templates

So I changed the name of my registration template from user_form.html to register.html.  I've also changed it in the urls.py file to reflect the new name, however when I try to go to the register page I get the following:

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist 
Exception Value:web/user_form.html 

Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:

Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:

../swl/root/lib/pythpy2.7.egg/django/contrib/admin/templates/web/user_form.html (File does not exist)

../django/contrib/auth/templates/web/user_form.html (File does not exist)

../templates/web/user_form.html (File does not exist)

..tastypie/templates/web/user_form.html (File does not exist)

../bootstrap3/templates/web/user_form.html (File does not exist)

../web/templates/web/user_form.html (File does not exist)
```

Why would the template loader still be looking for the old filename?

edit: this is my url for register:

`url(r'register/?$',
        UserCreate.as_view(),
        {
            'template_name':'accounts/register.html'
        },
        name = 'register'),`

Comment: Show what you changed in urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace all `user_form.html` to `registration.html` in all files. You can use `Find/replace in files` feature (or something similar) of your text editor or IDE.

Change `url` to:

```
url(r'register/?$',
    UserCreate.as_view(template_name='accounts/register.html'),
    name = 'register')
```

Comment: thanks @valdimir, I did that and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: @user5852854 Try to change `UserCreate.as_view(...)`.

Comment: what would I change it to?

Comment: you sir are fantastic - Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to ask this 6 years later, but what did you change it to? "{" to "("?

Answer (score 0):

The class-based views will attempt to use a default template name when no name is explicitly declared.  (The CreateView uses (appname)/(model)_form.html)  Your choices are:

1. Name your template using the default name
2. Specify the template in the URL (as in Vladimir's answer)
3. Specify the template name in the view code like so:

   class UserCreate(CreateView):

   ```
   template_name = "accounts/register.html"
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Restart the apache server.
For Ubuntu server 20:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```